# How can I specialize std::common_type<A,B> so that it's naturally commutative?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

[`std::common_type<T1, ..., TN>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) is a helper template in C++ which can find the common type which all of `T1` ... `TN` are implicitly convertible to.

According the C++ spec, a user may specialize `std::common_type<T1,T2>` if certain conditions apply, and:

> `std::common_type<T1, T2>::type` and `std::common_type<T2, T1>::type` must denote the same type.

However, `common_type<T1, T2>` might be a very complicated specialization for user types `T1` and `T2`:

```
namespace std {

    template <typename T1, complicated_constraint_of<T1> T2, ...>
    struct common_type<complicated_expression_of<T1, ...>, complicated_expression_of<T2, ...>> {
        using type = complicated_type_expression_of<T1,T2>;
    };

}
```

In general, the constraint expressions are not necessarily symmetrical (for example, we might specify that `T2` is a base of `T1`). This means that to preserve symmetry, we'd need to rewrite the entire specialization with `T1` and `T2` reversed, but doing that without making any mistake is extremely difficult and fragile.

How can I robustly define a commutative specialization of `common_type<T1,T2>` for my own types?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me. The order shouldn't really matter when determining a possibly common type for an abitrary number of parameters. Your solution only solves your specific use-case and not the general problem.

Comment: @super The fact that the order "shouldn't matter" *is* the problem that I am trying to solve! If I write the complicated specialization of `common_type` again with `T1` and `T2` reversed, and I type it wrong (or someone later changes one but not the other), then I've broken that requirement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the C++20 solution I came up with:

```
// define concept of `common_type<A,B>` existing
template <typename A, typename B>
concept has_in_common_ordered = requires { common_type<A,B>::type; };

namespace std {
    
    // define common_type<A,B> if common_type<B,A>::type exists:
    template <typename A, has_in_common_ordered<A> B>
    struct common_type<A,B> : public common_type<B,A> {};
    
}
```

Now, with the above, the following should compile:

```
struct X {};
struct Y {};

namespace std {
    
    template<>
    struct common_type<X,Y> {
        using type = X; // or whatever
    };
    
}

int main() {
    // even though we only specialized for one ordering,
    // both orderings now exist:
    std::common_type<X,Y>::type a;
    std::common_type<Y,X>::type b;
}
```

I think one of two things is possible:

1. This is a natural technique that should really just be part of the standard definition of `std::common_type`.
2. This is extremely evil and you should never do it, for subtle reasons.

I await someone to tell me which one it is in the comments. ;)

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer, but like a part of the original question.

Comment: @Evg It could certainly be organized in an alternative way, but it's a proposed answer which could be accepted as-is or discarded based on discussion and competing answers. :)

Comment: `requires { typename common_type<A,B>::type; }` will be more idiomatic and readable. No dummy variable, no random `true`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks! Implemented your suggestion; I knew there had to be something more idiomatic than what was there.

Comment: A requirement of the specialization is *"At least one of T1 and T2 depends on a user-defined type"*. your partial specialization with concept doesn't match that requirement...

Comment: The solution seems brilliant! But it doesn't seem to actually work: https://godbolt.org/z/WGEGPx4ns -- seems that there is a need to amend the concept a bit, adding `typename`: https://godbolt.org/z/cxoj9na8M -- or without the concept: https://godbolt.org/z/qzndeeo94 -- and still @Jarod42 comment is valid: the specialization is too generic and it doesn't match the requirement of having one of the arguments be user-defined.